# ReadProcessMemory declaration

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, readprocessmemory

I currently have it defined as

```
 Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory1 Lib "kernel32" Alias "ReadProcessMemory" (ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As Integer, ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Integer) As Integer
```

and I have another declaration for each type. 
I'm trying to use this instead

```
 <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory( _
    ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lpBaseAddress As Integer, _
    <Out()> ByRef lpBuffer As Byte(), _
    ByVal dwSize As Integer, _
    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

Which is off pvinvoke.net, heres how I'm trying to use it:

```
Public Shared Function Int(address As Integer)
    Dim buffer(3) As Byte
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, address, buffer, 4, 0)
    Return BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0)
End Function
```

This errors and says Attempt to read or write protected memory, but I use the old RPM declaration I have like this and it works fine.

```
Public Shared Function Int(address As Integer)
    Dim buffer As Integer
    ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, address, buffer, 4, 0)
    Return buffer
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm struggling to find where you got that from pinvoke.net. All the ones I can see [here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadProcessMemory.html) use `IntPtr` rather than `Integer` for both the current (Jul 26) and previous (May 10) revisions

Comment: [The one here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ReadProcessMemory.html) is wrong.  It looks like an orphan since it is under "user32".

Comment: Oh woops I changed that on my path to see if that would fix anything. It also says in the notes on the pinvoke to change the byval to byref for lpBuffer. I just changed it all back and it bloody fixed it! I shouldn't read them dam notes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your p/invoke declaration is wrong. It should be:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory( _
    ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, _
    ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, _
    <Out()> ByVal lpBuffer As Byte(), _
    ByVal dwSize As IntPtr, _
    ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function
```

Comment: It was actually the ByVal lpBuffer As Byte() part because I changed it to ByRef because thats what it said in the notes on the pinvoke page. Obviously thats the wrong thing to do.

Comment: That was the problem in your 32 bit process. But `SIZE_T` is pointer sized. And quite clearly `lpBaseAddress` is pointer sized, it being a pointer. So, if you think that you might ever be using this code in a 64 bit process, you'll want the declaration in my answer.